# ERROR AL INSERTAR DATOS EN UNA TABLA CON UN STORE PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Creé un store procedure para cagar datos a un tabla, pero al momento de insertarlos aparecen solamente 0.
¿Por qué ocurre esto?

**Tabla**

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla_general` (
  `equipo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `partidos_jugados` int NOT NULL,
  `partidos_ganados` int NOT NULL,
  `partidos_empatados` int NOT NULL,
  `partidos_perdidos` int NOT NULL,
  `puntos` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`equipo`)
)
```

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_alta_tabla_general`(in equi varchar(30), in parti_jug int, in parti_gana int, in parti_emp int, in parti_perd int, in punt int)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tabla_general VALUES (equipo,partidos_jugados,partidos_ganados,partidos_empatados,partidos_perdidos,puntos);

END
```

[image: IMAGEN QUE MUESTRA LA TABLA DESPUÉS DE INSERTAR LOS DATOS]

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en tu procedimiento almacenado los nombre de los datos que envias como parametros no son iguales a los que utilizas en el insert into, quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_alta_tabla_general`(in equi varchar(30), in parti_jug int, in parti_gana int, in parti_emp int, in parti_perd int, in punt int)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tabla_general VALUES (equi,parti_jug,parti_gana,parti_emp,parti_perd,punt);
END
```